# CakePHP ACL - Not able to access controller although I am Using $this->Auth->allow('index','view')

Tags: cakephp, acl

All,

Here I am with CakePHP ACL again. After many headaches, I was able to get [Alaxos ACL](http://www.alaxos.ch/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl) to work for me. I set group permission, etc, and it works great. However, I am having issue with one controller that does not make sense to me at all...

- In this controller `articles_controller.php` it looks like `beforeFilter()` has not effect

In my `app_controller.php` I have

```
function beforeFilter(){
    ...
    $this->Auth->allow('display') //To make sure all my pages are plublic, like about_us
}
```

In all my controllers including `articles_controller.php` I have the following code

```
...
function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
}
....
```

However, when I access this controller neither the index or view actions works. I get a `YOU ARE NOT AUTHORIZED TO ACCESS THAT LOCATION` error. The only time that controller works is if I change the `$this->Auth->allow('display') to`('*') in the `app_controller.php`'s `beforeFilter()`.

I am not sure what to do. Isnt `$this->Auth->allow('index','view')` making these 2 actions public regardless of ACL says? I am only able to access them when logged in. Same actions in other controllers work just fine. Nothing else is out of the ordinary...

What can I do, or where should I look next. Why?

===========================================================================================

And to add,

I have the following code in my `articles_controller.php`:

```
 $this->set('articles',$articles);
 $this->set('topfive_articles',$topfive_articles);
 $this->set('other_articles',$other_articles);
 $this->set('categories',$categories);
```

If I comment all those out, AUTH now gives me access to the action/view, but it displays `undefined variable` errors. Also, if I comment out, ie. 3 of 4, nothing happens. I only get thru if I comment out all 4 variables....

I have not idea what is going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

================================================================================

After many hours of researching and trying I came to a simple conclusion that was so obvious that I am not sure why I missed it.

In `articles_controller.php` I have other actions besides `index, view, edit, delete, admin_xxx`. I have among others `getArticleComments, mostViewedArticle`

I am not sure if it is the correct way, most likely it is not, but I use requestAction to process these actions and most into an ELEMENT which is displayed in the view.

I basically had to tell Auth to allow these actions to be public as well as the index and view.

```
$this->Auth->allow(
            'index',
            'view',
            'getTotalComments',
            'mostComments',
            'childrenComments',
            'getRelated',
            'getArticleComments',
            'mostViewed'
     );
```

Voila! As soon as I did that, problem solved... WOW!